# Is there a way to save the pytorch model for environment without pytorch package?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

We are training a model for a small minimal dependency software. The developer refused to include the PyTorch in their independence.

Is there a way to save the pytorch model in a way that they can load the model without PyTorch? or compile the model into a static/dynamic library?

**Training part**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

load_build_dataset()
train()
torch.save('MLmodel.a') # pseudocode.
```

**Inference part**

```
# PyBind11 C++
import MLmodel

A =np.array([...,])

Result = MLmodel.predict(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can export the trained model to [ONNX](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html) and run inference without pytorch

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will try.